# Does keras.evaluate use keras.predict

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, predict, evaluate

I've built a machine learning model with tensorflow and keras and when I test it with 'evaluate' I get pretty good scores. But then when I actually want to use the model I use 'predict' and then it predicts a lot wrong.

Here I have to add the information that for the evaluation I used some data I didn't use for training and when I use predict it even gets data wrong which I used for training.

So my question is, does 'evaluate' do something fundamentally different than using 'predict' and calculating the score of the predictions.

Sorry if this question is kinda stupid but it makes me mad that I get such good scores but then my model doesn't work.

Thank you in advance :)

PS: I think my whole code would be kinda overkill but I wanted to show you how i evaluate maybe I'm doing a mistake here:

At this point I have my test data in a dictionary called test_set where the keys are the categories (output of the model) and the values are the input for the model.

```
test_label = {}
for key in test_set:
    test_set[key] = np.array(test_set[key]).reshape(-1,255)
    test_label[key] = []
    for entry in test_set[key]:
        test_label[key].append(key)
    test_label[key] = np.array(test_label[key]).reshape(-1,18)

for key in test_set:
    model.evaluate(np.array(test_set[key]),test_label[key])
```

And this is my output:

```
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 124us/sample - loss: 0.0088 
- binary_accuracy: 0.9970
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 72us/sample - loss: 0.0556 - 
binary_accuracy: 0.9443
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 79us/sample - loss: 0.0556 - 
binary_accuracy: 0.9444
1000/1000 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0543 - 
binary_accuracy: 0.912 - 0s 73us/sample - loss: 0.0543 - binary_accuracy: 
0.9131
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 103us/sample - loss: 0.0045 
- binary_accuracy: 0.9963
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 70us/sample - loss: 
9.6615e-06 - binary_accuracy: 1.0000
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 79us/sample - loss: 0.0028 - 
binary_accuracy: 0.9970
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 99us/sample - loss: 1.9372e- 
05 - binary_accuracy: 1.0000
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 121us/sample - loss: 
9.1933e-04 - binary_accuracy: 0.9993
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 82us/sample - loss: 0.0169 - 
binary_accuracy: 0.9609
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 102us/sample - loss: 0.0098 
- binary_accuracy: 0.9998
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 103us/sample - loss: 0.0561 
- binary_accuracy: 0.9443
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 102us/sample - loss: 0.0495 
- binary_accuracy: 0.9564
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 76us/sample - loss: 0.0590 - 
binary_accuracy: 0.9444
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 83us/sample - loss: 0.0327 - 
 binary_accuracy: 0.9534
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 80us/sample - loss: 0.0303 - 
binary_accuracy: 0.9561
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 86us/sample - loss: 0.0345 - 
binary_accuracy: 0.9421
```

So i get pretty good scores for every category but then when I iterate over some data and use predict for every entry it gets in some categories every entry wrong.

Would be so glad if anyone knows something helpful.

Comment: The problem is not with predict, but how you interpret the output of the model, so you have to show us how do you go from model predictions to classes.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. This was indeed very stupid by me ^^ sorry to everyone who wasted time reading this. I used binary accuracy but I should've used categorical accuracy.